# Chrome fails to start, crashes instead

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, ubuntu-16.04

I have been tasked with making a simple scraper for an app. I was able to run it locally however upon running on a server (Ubuntu 16.04) I have gone through an abundance of errors the latest being selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed. Something very strange was that prior to this mess the script actually ran to my surprise only once before bugging out again.

I have already tried other solutions like making sure chromedriver-chrome versions match, uninstalling to reinstall, adding headless arguments, specifying the path to the .exe. This just leads to a circle of the same errors getting re-ignited over and over again.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import json
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# Adjusting selenium to a headless browser      
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/google-chrome'
PATH = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')


# Automating the Login straight to the Table
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH, chrome_options=options)
browser.implicitly_wait(10) # delay to let js render
url = "site"
browser.get(url)
username = browser.find_element_by_id("UserName") #username form field
password = browser.find_element_by_id("Password") #password form field
username.send_keys("USER")
password.send_keys("PASS")
log_button = browser.find_element_by_id("login")
log_button.click()

# the code after is the scraper which is functioning
```

The script is eventually supposed to login to a page and scrape out certain info from a table.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but I've had a lot better luck with the gecko driver in Ubuntu; https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases